# How to use Evince to loop over ps files in current folder?

Tags: evince, nautilus-script

I love Evince, I use it as an image viewer of my eps figures (a one-page document). It's super light-weight and clean. I also like how it re-renders the ps documents as you zoom-in and zoom-out, this feature is missing from other image viewers.

The problem is that evince can only open one file/image at each time, this is very annoying, the `next` button only works for next page, it does not work to search for the next ps/eps file in the current folder. Any ideas?

Comment: Select all and open at once?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a small nautilus script to use `evince` to loop over `ps` files in current folder. Here is the script,

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
var="$(dirname "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS")"
evince "$1" &
for i in "$var"/*.ps
do
    if [[ "$i" != "$1" ]]; then
        zenity --question --title="Choose an option" --text="No: To exit any time\nYes: Move to next file" --width="300"
        if [ $? = 0 ]; then
            #killall evince  #Remove the hash if you want to open next ps file after closing the previous file.
            sleep 1
            evince "$i" &
        else
            notify-send "$(basename "$0")" "Slide-show is aborted prematurely"
            exit 0
        fi
    fi
done
notify-send "$(basename "$0")" "No file left to show"
```

### Steps to install the script

- Say the above script name is `evince slide show`. If you are using Ubuntu 12.04 save the script in `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/`, For Ubuntu 13.04 or later save it in `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/`.
- Make the script executable. It will not work otherwise. Right click on the script, then go to **Properties >> Permissions** and **check the box corresponds to Execute**

### How to use the script

- Go to a folder containing `ps` files. Right click on any `ps` file. Choose the option **evince slide show** under **Scripts**.

[image]

- Selected `ps` file will be open in `evince`. At the same time you will get an option in a `zenity` pop-up dialogue box,

[image]

- If you choose "yes" next `ps` file will be opened in evince. You will get similar option for all `ps` files in your current directory. If you choose "No" the script will be terminated immediately.

---

**Note:**

Similar script can be used for `.pdf` file also. One need to replace the line `for i in "$var"/*.ps` with `for i in "$var"/*.pdf`.